# Bootstrap: Navbar not fixed to very top has like 40px padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with twitter bootstrap this is how my navbar looks like:
[image: Bootstrap navbar is in bue]

There is a gap between the top of the page and the navbar.
I tried using

> .navbar{
>       position: fixed !important;
>       top: 0px;     padding: 0px;   margin: 0px; }

in my css file but its still not working. It looks like this in mobile and desktop (with the responsive css). I tried putting my sites css after the responsive css and before but it doesn't do anything. Does anyone have any idea why is this so?

THe navbar data from bootstrap.css:

```
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-inner {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 940px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}

.navbar .nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats your CSS/HTML code for the navbar?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make your you body,html doesnt have any padding to,

```
html, body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to give one more piece of advice in case anyone googles this and has the same problem as me. Always, always make sure you are not over looking a much more simple solution to this problem. In my case, the navbar was pushed down as if some part of the document had approx. ~40px of padding but, the issue was a stray character being hidden above the navbar like so:

```
<script>
*JavaScript would go here*
\</script>  <!-- Here you can see the offending backslash before the '</script> tag and it was hidden due to it being a similar color to my dark background. -->

    <body id="wrapper">
{% block navbar %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--- Logo -->
<!--*rest of the file*-->
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my problem. I defined a script element in the head section and it had a single period after it, like so `<script>link here</script>.` The really perplexing thing is this worked for months until I added a new framework after this script element. Only then did this error start occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `navbar-inner`?
For a navbar you will need this hierarchy of classes and divs:

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether `body` has `padding-top` or `margin-top`. If you'are directly trying to edit the bootstrap docs page, it has `padding-top` for body so that the content won't get wrapped under the fixed navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to reset the the padding and margin for all the elements

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
```

Also if the content of the inside the nav bar has a margin top it can sometimes push it also.